# line 12: unrecognized rule in lex programming

Tags: yacc, lex

I am a beginner to Lex Programming and I am getting this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UCWk.png) "q1.l", line 12: unrecognized rule.

Here is my code

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int count=0;
%}
op [+-*/]
letter [a-zA-Z]
digitt [0-9]
id {letter}*|({letter}{digitt})+
notid ({digitt}{letter})+
%%
[\t\n]+
("int")|("float")|("char")|("case")|("default")| ("if")|("for")|("printf")|("scanf") {printf("%s is a keyword\n", yytext);}
{id} {printf("%s is an identifier\n", yytext); count++;}
{notid} {printf("%s is not an identifier\n", yytext);}
%%
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char file[10];
fp=fopen(input,"r");
yyin=fp;
yylex();
printf("Total identifiers are: %d\n", count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a space between `default` and `if`.

Comment: Also, `("int")|("float")` is equivalent to `"int"|"float"`; the parentheses aren't doing anything for you.  The double quotes aren't necessary; none of the identifiers contain regex operators that require quoting.